# Why each JavaFX application flash on my system?

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, kde-plasma

I had created simple app using `NetBeans` wizard but it was flashing while creating `alert` I recreated it but same thing happen.

> When I click on `button` it does flash rectangular region at top left corner of the screen and then load `Alert`.

Here is code :

```
public class MyAlert extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

FXML.fxml:

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="myalert.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Button layoutX="126" layoutY="90" text="Click Me!" onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

ControllerClass:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR);
        alert.setTitle("Message");
        alert.setHeaderText("Error Message");
        alert.show();
    }
```

> I'm using JDK 1.8.0 u131
>   With old processor

- Processor: 2* Pentium@ Dual-Core CPU E5300 @ 2.60GH
- Memory: 1.9 GiB of RAM
- OS Kubuntu 18.04

Don't know if this is case.

Comment: Is this a feature enabled by a system preference or accessibility setting on your machine?

Comment: Which feature you are talking about. I just provided my pc configuration if it is a case of flashing the application.

Comment: I think it is my OS problem. I've checked on windows it seems fine.  I'm getting problem with Linux KDE Plasma.

Comment: You might want to edit your question to include additional details about OS version and relevant settings.

Comment: I got it fixed, my compositor was crashed and I reapply it and that solved the problem. Thank you so much for the attention.

Comment: Excellent; you are welcome. Note that you can [answer your own question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/17463/163188). Details and maybe a [*screenshot*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) might help future visitors.

Comment: Was thinking to delete it

Comment: A solved problem seems valuable, but I defer to you.

Comment: Ok I'll change my question and then will add answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked on windows 7 if getting same behavior, but application run smoothly without flash as I've mentioned in my question.

I'm using `Kubuntu 18.04` and `Desktop Effects` are enabled and day ago `Compositor` was failed and that was the reason of flashing screen when launching `Frame` or `Alert` dialog.

The Compositor can be found in the System Settings under Display and Monitor > Compositor.

I re-enabled and problem is solved.

> This question is helpful only for `KDE Plasma Desktop` users.